# Can Fastlane check whether an app update is rejected by the PlayStore?

Tags: android, google-play, continuous-deployment, fastlane

I use Fastlane to update a big number of apps. Sometimes Google rejects an update for legal reasons. It's easy to resolve the rejection, but the problem is I often don't learn about it until I receive complaints from users.

Goal: I would like to use Fastlane to proactively check whether an update for a specific app has been rejected. (then I can easily use this for all my apps in a loop)

It's not feasible to check that manually on every update. And I don't have access to the email accounts to most apps, so I don't see the standard emails sent when there are rejections.

By the way, the Fastlane action "google_play_track_version_codes" allows you to check what version codes are currently in the store, but it shows the ones of rejected updates just like any other. So it can't be used to find out whether an update is successful.

Comment: Some background information on fastlane and Google Play Store: The actions interacting with Play Store use an official Google API called "Android Publisher API", today also called "Google Play Developer API". Here is the documentation on the version currently in use: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/archive/v2/ If that information is in there, we can probably surface it in an action as well.

Comment: (That being said, maybe create an issue in the fastlane repo - discussion is quite difficult [and unwanted] here on StackOverflow). Then we can dive deeper.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I checked and didn't find such functionality on the Google API (should have done this first...). I sent them a request to implement it. Keeping my fingers crossed now.

Comment: Awesome! Please also create the issue over at fastlane, then we can track it there as well and maybe find other solutions to that problem. We have some creative users :)